# How do I convert strings in a dataframe column to int or float

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, one-hot-encoding

Encoding the column seperately works ,but when I try it on the dataset directly it throws an error.
The error is something like this.
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'g'`

Comment: You might be better asking on StackOverflow. Or at least give an example of your dataframe. If you have a `g` in your column, how could Pandas/Python known how you want that to be converted to a float?

Comment: I got the issue resolved. Thank you for your time.@n1k31t4